# Python-based Gallery web applications?

Tags: python, web-applications, gallery

I'm trying to cut my last dependencies on PHP and MySQL. The last stumbling block is a image gallery I set up for a client a while ago. The whole website is built around [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Zine](http://zine.pocoo.org/), except for the image gallery, which is based on [plogger](http://www.plogger.org/). I'd love to replace plogger with a Python solution. Requirements include:

- good admin interface with batch upload (my client thinks FTP is some kind of disease)
- uses a templating system (e.g. Jinja)
- WSGI interface
- supports PostgreSQL
- bonus points if it is a Django app

I looked at [django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/), which seems to be a good base for building a gallery app. But it isn't really a drop-in gallery app, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [django-photo-gallery](http://code.google.com/p/django-photo-gallery), [django photo album](http://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-photo-albums/) and another [django-photo-gallery](http://www.ohloh.net/p/django-photo-gallery) (don't know if its the same one.)

Anything else, and you'll have to make your own.

Comment: django-photo-album looks interesting. Thanks! (BTW: real URL is http://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-photo-albums/, I hate those softpedia guys!)